# Set Notification Bar same color than Navigation Bar Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a project with Xamarin Forms. 
I followed the James Montemagno's guide https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/
but I can't get the same color in the Notification bar and Navigation Bar

I'm setting the Navigation bar color in App XAML like this

```
     <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#3b5998"/>
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

The **style.xml** and the **values-v21/style.xml** are the same that in the guide

```
 <resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>

<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#3b5998</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I set the `statusBarColor` in the values-v21/style.xml, and a rare thing is that when I start to debug the application the Notifications bar get the color I set, but then when the application finish starting, it get back to the original color.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

I want to set the color of the Notifications Bar the same as Navigation Bar.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to override the `colorPrimaryDark` style to achieve what I want.

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3b5998</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3b5998</item>
</style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The status bar and the action bar can be set to the same colour by using the following xml in the values/Styles.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Override the android colour scheme -->
       <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/my_primary</item>
       <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/my_primary</item>        
    </style>
</resources>
```

Do also make sure that you have the style included in the androidManifest.xml and you have custom colours set in the values/Colours.xml file.

```
<application android:label="Settings" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/myTheme"></application>
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, I tried what you suggest but it doesn't work, the notifications bar stays with different color than the navigation bar